# setting color instead of drawable in selector causes crash

Tags: android

I want to have a background color that changes color according to the state of the view.

I tired creating it exactly like the example from Google (except I'm using colors from my resources instead of hardcoding the hex values :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:color="@color/transparent" />
    <item
        android:color="@color/gray_3"
        android:state_selected="true" />
</selector>
```

(this is located in `res/color`)

then I set this as a background to my view.but when I run the code, I get a crash with this error:

```
Binary XML file line #3: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or    child tag defining a drawable
```

It's telling me that the "item" tag in my selector needs `drawable`, not `color` to define the color.

when I change it to a drawable, as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable ="@color/transparent" />
    <item
        android:drawable ="@color/gray_3"
        android:state_selected="true" />
</selector>
```

that crash goes away, but Android Studio gives me a lint warning saying that "color" is required

my only suspicion is that maybe I'm not supposed to set the view background as a color selector

Comment: where did you placed that resource? It should be placed under color res.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

drawable xml code:-

transparent color use like this

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/selected" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

- Define @color/selected in color xml.

Answer (score 0):

As Google's documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource), you should not define the default statement in the first item.
 Here's the example they provide.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#ffff0000"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="#ff000000"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

**Try using hex color codes instead of color values.**